# DataBase replication - change datbase context

Tags: database

Currently, I have a problem that I cannot create replication on database restored from backup.
The production database is running transactional replication. 
A backup was made and then database was restored on the test server under the same name.
Replication was running on the test server before.
Now I cannot create replication on the test server. When I try to create a publication I get the message: Sql server could not create publication "test".
Publication "test" does not exists. Object "test" does not exist or is not a valid object for this operation. Change database context to "Database name"

I have tried all the procedures available to clean up / drop replication but is not helping. As far as I know it was a normal full backup and a normal restore datatabse done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This does not sound like a programming question.